# Monitor network load on ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: server, remote-access, monitoring, traffic

I wanted a lightweight tool so that I can remotely monitor the network load on my server(apache2)

I want to know the

- bandwidth usage
- the IP addresses of the traffic

Any tool in mind guys?

Answer (score 0):

I don't known what you exactly wont ..., `iptarf` is nice network monitor tool
With `iptraf` you can see general statistic per interface, sessions, traffic per protocol/port ...

Also `bmon` is good tool to see curent traffic load and basic graphic and can record history.

`slurm` is also nice

All cen be install with `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get install bmon
sudo apr-get install slurm
sudo apt-get install iptraf
```

Also have `man` pages for all.

Comment: Sorry if it was ambiguous. What I wanted was to monitor my server remotely for incoming traffic.

Comment: This, proposed tool, can use only in local aka ssh to server and run tool. If you want from remote pc to monitor server interface do not forget that in that case on server must be installed some client witch will send data to server.